# Matlab compressing and decompressing a jpg file

Tags: image, matlab, compression

I am trying to compress and decompress a jpg file with matlab, but I am having issues finding a source code for that.
So I need help with that. I tried some codes from mathworks.com but it didn't work properly..
Thank you in advance..

codes from mathworks website but it didn't give me the original photo I previously compressed.

Comment: jpeg uses a lossy compression algorithm, so it’s no surprise if the images are not identical. You have given us no images, code, or what comparison method you used from which we might be able to debug your problem. Please read how to provide a [mre].